# JavaScript code to simulate a mouse click on an iframe embedded video

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe in a HTML document and need to force or simulate a click on the screen to cause a video to play. Essentially bypassing "autoplay" as that is not working. Tried various ways in JavaScript but not working.

HTML code for autoplay of iframe.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(.click, 3000);
}
document.getElementById('myButton').click()
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<iframe id="myButton" style="max-width: 100%; display: block; margin: auto;" src="https://www.ministeriotv.com/home/ejwM/48/" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" align="middle" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

get error: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 17,
  "colno": 22
}
thoughts????

Comment: Don't you think that maybe there's a reason `autoplay` doesn't work, and therefore any attempts to bypass it probably won't work either? What is your goal here, exactly?

Comment: well the goal here is exactly to automate the stream refresh. The browser disables autoplay as per new google policies. A click on the page will make it play - this is why I am asking to simulate a click on the page via java. How in your thoughts are these associated (autoplay and a simulated click) to where you think it wont work?